# Calculate the Average Price of Each Product in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

Z = pd.DataFrame({'Product': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Orange], 'Selling Price': [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.2]})
```

There are thousands of unique products and hundreds of millions of selling prices.
How could I efficiently report the average selling price of each unique product?

```
Result = pd.DataFrame({'Product': ['Apple', 'Orange'], 'Average Selling Price': [1.2, 2.15]})
```

The challenge is that the data is stored in hundreds of different .csv files (file names stored in a list `files`) that I cannot load simultaneously into my environment.  So I would do something like

```
for i in files:
     X = pd.read_csv(i)
     # add unique products to the data frame Z
     # add the sum of their selling prices to Z
     # add the number of times the product was sold

# for each unique product, divide the sum of selling prices by the number of times that product was sold
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
From your post, you seem to be stuck on merging the data into one data frame *and* groupby / mean.  Both of those are covered in any Pandas tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in files:
    X = pd.read_csv(i)
    X_agg = X.groupby('Product', as_index=False).agg({'Selling Price':['count', 'sum']})
    X_agg.columns = ['Product', 'sale_count', 'selling_sum']
    final_df = pd.concat([final_df, X_agg])
    final_df = final_df.groupby('Product', as_index=False).agg({'sale_count':'sum', 'selling_sum':'sum'})
```